# How to get remote hostname via Expect?

Tags: unix, expect, hostname

I am trying to automate some commands on a remote Unix system using Expect, which try to fetch data based on the *remote* hostname. An example,

```
expect -re $prompt
send "lsnrctl status listener_`hostname`\r"
```

The problem is, when run via Expect, this command fetches the local hostname instead of the remote one, leading to no useful output.

What changes to I need to make to the Expect script to make the command fetch the remote hostname? Or do I need to make any changes to the command itself?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes. Strings in single quotes aren't interpreted by the local shell:

```
expect -re $prompt 
send 'lsnrctl status listener_`hostname`\r'
```

Comment: Its not being interpreted by the remote shell as well - the `hostname` part stays as it is while execution.